# AWS ETL Job to write data to s3 bucket in csv format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am completly new to AWS, and need your support to point me to right direction on my requirement.

**Requirement:**

- I need to read multiple csv files from s3 bucket, union the data perform some transformation and load it to another s3 bucket.

**Issue:**

- I understand that Lambda is one of the option to do the same, but the data is huge so i belive at somepoint 15min limitation will be a issue to me.
- Also for Glue ETL, fom what i read i understand it does suport the output to be s3.

**Ask**

- Could you suggest any other ELT services and the link to help me get started.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the "transformation" that you wish to perform? If it is SQL-like, then Amazon Athena would be ideal for the task. Please Edit your question to provide more details about what you are wanting to do with the data.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how athena help here? For my use case my source and target would be s3. Also by transformation i mean basic derivations like cleaning the column, concatenation, aggregation which can be handled by pandas.

Comment: Amazon Athena can perform SQL operations against multiple files stores in Amazon S3. The output can be sent to S3 by using `CREATE TABLE AS`. So, it works extremely well if your transformation can be written as SQL. For an example, see: [Extract, Transform and Load data into S3 data lake using CTAS and INSERT INTO statements in Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/extract-transform-and-load-data-into-s3-data-lake-using-ctas-and-insert-into-statements-in-amazon-athena/) and [Creating a table from query results (CTAS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html)